# Update duplicate email addresses on mysql database table

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a huge database that I have almost over 10k row in my user table and there are 2700 duplicate email addresses.

Basically the application did not limit the users from registering their accounts with the same email address over and over again. I have cleaned the multiple ones -more than 2 times- manually, there weren't many, but there are 2700 email addresses with duplicate value occur at least 2 times. So I want to update the duplicate email addresses and change the email address with a smaller id number to something like from "email@mail.com" to "1email@mail.com", basically adding "1" to the beginning of all duplicate email addresses. I can select and display the duplicate email addresses but could not find the way to update only one of the email addresses and leave the other on untouched.

My table structure is like `id` `username` `email` `password`.

Comment: if you have an id I don't know what problem  you are facing

Comment: @ashwintastic super new at mysql so can not even create the logic and wrap my mind around it. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE table_name SET email="1email@mail.com"  where id = "whatever smaller id you have"

Comment: @ashwintastic I have updated the question for more clarification so it is not that there is only one email address, there are around 2700 with duplicate email address.

Comment: Well you changed the question after I posted an answer. Why would you want to change an email address to presumably one that is not valid instead of just deleting the extraneous rows?

Comment: I would just delete the duplicates personally, but updating the duplicate ones is what I have been asked for so.

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?)(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query). You should use site like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to create a sample `my_table` with a few duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have MySQL 8:

Here I am just prepending the `id` of the row to the email address:

```
UPDATE my_table JOIN (
    SELECT email, MAX(id) AS max_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM my_table
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING cnt > 1
) sq ON my_table.email = sq.email AND my_table.id <> sq.max_id
SET my_table.email = CONCAT( my_table.id, my_table.email)
;
```

[See DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bqQWk9MR12UigKyMSYux4G/1)

The inner query:

```
SELECT email, MAX(id) AS max_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM my_table
GROUP BY email
HAVING cnt > 1
```

looks for all emails that that are duplicated (i.e. there is more than one row with the same email address) and computes the row that has the maximum `id` value for each email address. For the sample data in my DB-Fiddle demo, it would return the following:

```
| email            | max_id | cnt |
| ---------------- | ------ | --- |
| emaila@dummy.com | 3      | 3   |
| emailb@dummy.com | 5      | 2   |
```

The above inner query is aliased as table `sq`.

Now if I join `my_table` with the above query as follows:

```
SELECT my_table.* from my_table join (
  SELECT email, MAX(id) AS max_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM my_table
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING cnt > 1
) sq on my_table.email = sq.email and my_table.id <> sq.max_id
```

I get:

```
| id  | email            |
| --- | ---------------- |
| 1   | emaila@dummy.com |
| 2   | emaila@dummy.com |
| 4   | emailb@dummy.com |
```

because I am selecting from `my_table` all rows that have duplicate email addresses (condition `my_table.email = sq.email` except for the rows that have the highest value of `id` for each email address (condition `my_table.id <> sq.max_id`).

It is the ids from the above join whose email addresses are to be modified.

Comment: The table creation in the above DB-Fiddle is what the OP should have created for people to fork so that they would have something tangible to work with.

Comment: This answer is correct I just want to understand what JOIN in doing here ??

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That has solved the issue. Appreciated it.

Comment: I will update the answer and provide an explanations (as best as I can).

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     email, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY id) rn
              FROM sourcetable )
UPDATE sourcetable src, cte
SET src.email = CONCAT(rn - 1, src.email)
WHERE src.id = cte.id
  AND cte.rn > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/trSvHKvmaV1ZzMy8ggjzuF/0)

---

> I want to update the duplicate email addresses and change the email address **with a smaller id** number

If so the ordering in window function must be reversed:

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT id, 
                     email, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY id DESC) rn
              FROM sourcetable )
UPDATE sourcetable src, cte
SET src.email = CONCAT(rn - 1, src.email)
WHERE src.id = cte.id
  AND cte.rn > 1;
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/trSvHKvmaV1ZzMy8ggjzuF/1)

Comment: The OP wants to change the email addresses with the *smallest* ids; I believe this changes the largest.

Comment: Add the `DESC` to your *actual* answer. I will upvote you "on spec.*

Comment: @Booboo No problems. Updated.